# How should I place files on apache2 HTTP server

Tags: linux, apache, http

I am on Kali linux which comes with the apache2 http installed. Under /var/www/ there is a index.html file which is the default index page that will show up on localhost. I have this folder containing all my .html .css .js  and some pictures that I want to put on the Apache2 server. Should I just copy/paste the folder under /var/www ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the traditional way to do it.

if you have virtualhosts or something a bit more complex then you might consider something else but typically people just drop everything in under /var/www (or the equivalent for a given disto or OS )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though you may need to adjust the accsess rights, and if you want you can use the apache config, or mount --bind, or git clone/pull. Start with the simple option then look into the other options to see if they offer you any benefit.